# Is my form safe?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have been trying to read up a lot about trying to get a safe html form to email me something. I have created a form but I'm curious about it's safety. I haven't added the e-mail controls yet.

Since it will be up on a website I'm terrified of any injections. What I have done so far is use the htmlentities() to protect the action, used the test_input function from w3 schools and used the require function but I know that can be easily taken out.

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
        // define variables and set to empty values
        $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";
        function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;}
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
            $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
            $website = test_input($_POST["telnr"]);
            $comment = test_input($_POST["message"]);
            echo"Bedankt voor het invullen, we nemen zo snel mogelijk contact met u op.";
            }
            else{
            ?>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">naam</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="naam" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">e-mail</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="e-mail" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">tel.nr</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="telnr" placeholder="telefoonnummer" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">bericht</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="bericht" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row text-center">
                    <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Verstuur bericht!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What does it *do*? You don't seem to mail or save the data.

Comment: It does nothing yet as explained above. The lines that make the form mail still need to be added.

Comment: there are pre-defined functions to sanitize input: [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) (replaces your custom `test_input()`)

Comment: Thanks for that one, I'll start using that!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely good to [escape the `PHP_SELF` value](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html) although, unless you need the portability it provides, you can always simplify things a bit and hardcode the form target.